# Understanding Tensor Product

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider the operator $$e^{-i \hat{H} t/\hbar} = e^{-i (\hat{P} \otimes \hat{X}) t/\hbar},$$
where $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$ are position and momentum operator of two different systems.
We know that the momentum operator $$\hat{P} = - i \hbar \frac{d}{dX},$$ so 
 $$e^{-i \hat{H} t/\hbar} = e^{-(\frac{d}{dX} \otimes \hat{X}) t}.$$
But how should we interpret the above expression? What is the meaning of the tensor product in the power of the exponential? How can we simplify the exponential of tensor products?

Comment: To clarify, are these the momentum and position of a single particle or of two different systems? If the former, a tensor product doesn't really make much sense. Also, be aware that there one can probably do very little to 'simplify' that expression unless there is additional structure available. Why are you interested in this object? Where did you see it?

Comment: They are the operators for two different systems. I saw an operator similar to the above in a paper.

Comment: In that case, if you provide a link to the paper it will be easier to understand the context and provide an answer.

Comment: The paper simplifies the expression for $e^{-i\hat{X} \otimes \hat{x} t/\hbar}$ by using the decomposition $X = \int dX \ X \mid X \rangle \langle X \mid$, so that $$e^{-i \hat{X} \otimes \hat{x} t/\hbar} = \int dX \ |X \rangle \langle X \mid \otimes e^{-i X \hat{x} t}.$$ I want to do similar simplication for the above operator.

Comment: @nchar: Where are you seeing this? $$\int dX|X\rangle\langle X|\otimes e^{-iX\hat x t}$$ has no meaning in my mind. What is the difference between $\hat X$ and $\hat x$?

Comment: $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{x}$ are position operators of two different systems. To be precise, I saw the interaction picture Hamiltonian  $$\hat{H}^{I}(t) = \int dX |X\rangle \langle X| \otimes \sum_{k} C_{k} X \cos(\Omega t) \hat{x}_{k}(t)$$ in a paper and I'm trying to understand it.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which paper?

Comment: I think the spectral decomposition you are suggesting in the comments here is non-trivial and it needs a justification. It might be that this is all mathematically fine, but I have never encountered such a situation and I'd need to verify that you can actually take the spectral decomposition of one of the two factors. Of course, since $p$ and $x$ of the two independent systems commute, one could do spectral decomposition of the whole self-adjoint operator $p\otimes x$.